# Find by value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm struggling with some task in javascript. I have the following object:

```
const methods = {
    searchRanking: {
        id: 'tmEM6RoEPmUO',
        template: 'main_template',
        startUrl: 'https://www.amazon.de/s?k={value}',
        startValueOverrideName: 'url',

        dataProcessor: function (data) {
            return data.map(/*doe shit met data*/)
        }
    },

    productDetails: {
        id: 'tAewRCbTuuL5',
        template: 'main_template',
        startUrl: 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/{value}',
        startValName: 'url',

        dataProcessor: function (data) {
            return data.map(/*doe shit met data*/)
        }
    }

}
```

Every object has a processor method. I want to return the processor of the object that contains the id `tmEM6RoEPmUO`

I can loop through the keys and check for every key if it contains the given ID, but it seems like a workaround, is there a more efficient way?

Comment: *"I can loop through the keys and check for every key if it contains the given ID"* That is perfectly fine. Use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and `break` once a match is found

Comment: aah okay, wasnt completely sure thank you @adiga

Comment: If the items are sorted by ID then you can do a binary search for `O(log n)`. But it doesn't seem like they are ordered, so you can only do it in `O(n)` using a linear scan. Although, if you have a lot of lookups, you can just build a lookup table once for `O(n)` and then fetch items from it in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply loop through the keys and check. In that case time complexity will be `O(N)`. It will be like

```
let res = Object.values(obj).find(x => x.id === 'tmEM6RoEPmUO').dataProcessor()
```

But consider that you want an `O(1)` time complexity then you can create another object with keys equal to id of the object.

```
let newObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([_, v]) => [v.id, v]));
let res = newObj['tmEM6RoEPmUO'].dataProcessor()
```

Comment: The `const` keyword can also be used when this value will not be reassigned

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the desired object out into a constant, `method` and invoke its `dataProcessor` method with your arguments like so:

```
const method = Object.values(obj).find(o => o.id === 'tmEM6RoEPmUO');
method.dataProcessor(data);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score -2):

loop through all the key in object and check its id

```
for(let m of Object.keys(methods)){
 if(methods[m].id == "tmEM6RoEPmUO"){
  return methods[m].dataProcessor;
 }
}
```

Comment: And why is this -1?

Comment: OP knows the answer you just gave. He is asking for any better way _" is there a more efficient way?"_. (I didn't downvoted).

Comment: Ok then which one is more efficient i think all are same iterating through the props.

Comment: The second way in my answer  is more efficient. If OP wants to check for id many times then its better.